# Can't activate Xdebug on PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I am running Apache 2.2.19 and PHP 5.2.17. I wanted to configure debugging with Xdebug, so I went to xdebug.org and downloaded: php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6-nts.dll (I have php VC6 x86 version). I copied it to `c:\Program Files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6-nts.dll`

Edited PHP.ini (added):

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\host\xdebug.log"
zend_extension_ts="c:\Program Files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6-nts.dll"
```

But I still can't see in phpinfo() xdebug information - so it's not working.
Apache error log says:

```
Failed loading c:\Program Files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6-nts.dll
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in
```

Comment: Off topic, but important: PHP 5.2 has been completely unsupported for two years now. It has known security issues that have not and will not be patched. It is strongly recommended to upgrade to at least 5.3. (a lot of popular PHP software now requires 5.3 as well, so if you're using any third party software you may find you can't update that either until you've updated PHP, which will leave you with further security holes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using thread safe or non-thread safe PHP? It looks like the xdebug dll you downloaded is for non-thread safe. I think you can find this out using phpinfo(). This could be the cause of the problem.

If you are using thread safe PHP then try downloading the thread safe version of xdebug. This could help.

You can download it here: http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6.dll

Comment: Thank you, mate! it was: Thread Safety  enabled!